# Python SQL executemany statement doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, executemany

I am trying to execute a delete statement that checks if the table has any SKU that exists in the SKU column of the dataframe. And if it does, it deletes the row.

```
supplier_name = input("Enter supplier name of the supplier you are updating: ")
df = pd.read_csv("update.csv",sep=',')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
column = df["SKU"]
print(column)
query="""DELETE FROM price_calculations1(Supplier_Name, SKU) VALUES(?,?)"""
cursor.executemany(query,(supplier_name, column))
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Changed the code to;

```
cursor = mydb.cursor()
column = df["SKU"]
print(column)
query="""DELETE FROM price_calculations1 WHERE Supplier_Name=? AND SKU=?"""
cursor.executemany(query,(supplier_name, column))
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

It gives me the following error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Supplier_Name, SKU) VALUES(?,?)' at line 1
> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND SKU=?' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for a delete statement.

You can refer to the docs for more details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

The correct syntax would be:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name [[AS] tbl_alias]
    [PARTITION (partition_name [, partition_name] ...)]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

In your case, your statement should look like:

```
DELETE FROM price_calculations1
WHERE Supplier_Name=%s
AND SKU=%s
```

To use parameterized statements (aka prepared statements), you will have to create your cursor as follows:

```
cursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)
```

Also note that `executemany` expects an iterable of iterables (or a "sequence or parameters") and `supplier_name` is only a string, so you will have to change that, too.

Example of executemany from the docs:

```
data = [
  ('Jane', date(2005, 2, 12)),
  ('Joe', date(2006, 5, 23)),
  ('John', date(2010, 10, 3)),
]
stmt = "INSERT INTO employees (first_name, hire_date) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.executemany(stmt, data)
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Comment: Thanks for the second part, but even after changing the DELETE query, I'm still getting the same error. I tried that before as well, I don't know if I'm overlooking a small mistake.

Comment: I am not familiar with the mysql DB connector, but have tou tried to replace the ``?`` with ``%s`` ? (e.g. ``WHERE Supplier_Name=%s ...``)

Comment: Hm, I can only guess. According to [this example](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/) you should create the cursor with ``cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)`` (**and** use ``%s`` as placeholder) or in your case ``cursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)``. If that still does not help I'm running out of ideas.